# Adding additional Language Propeties to Liferay

Tags: properties, configuration, liferay, portlet

How do I add additional properties to Liferay.

I don't want to override the existing properties. I would like to add new properties on top of existing properties

I tried in this way, but no luck

```
<portlet>
        <portlet-name>search</portlet-name>
        <display-name>Search</display-name>
        <portlet-class>org.springframework.web.portlet.DispatcherPortlet</portlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <name>contextConfigLocation</name>
            <value>/WEB-INF/spring-config/search-portlet.xml</value>
        </init-param>
        <init-param>
            <name>config-template</name>
            <value>/WEB-INF/view/search/configuration.jsp</value>
        </init-param>        
        <expiration-cache>0</expiration-cache>
        <supports>
            <mime-type>text/html</mime-type>
            <portlet-mode>view</portlet-mode>
        </supports>
        <resource-bundle>Language</resource-bundle>
        .............
</portlet>
```

`I have placed Language.properties file under src/main/resources/`

However when I try to print `<liferay-ui:message key="test-lang-msg" />` I am not getting the value

Language.properties file
`test-lang-msg=Testing Language Properties File`

Comment: what do you get instead: Nothing, or just the key, e.g. "test-lang-msg"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your entry for  in portlet.xml is not correct.

Provide it like

```
<resource-bundle>resource.Language</resource-bundle>
```

HTH
Regards

Comment: still I am not getting the value :(

Comment: in the war, Language.properties file exist under WEB-INF/Classes/

Comment: Put your language file in content folder under source and provide <resource-bundle>content.Language</resource-bundle> . And see if it works

Comment: this worked pretty much. for future reference: I needed to create resource folder under src->main->resources->resource->Language.properties

Answer (score 0):

Check this out: http://www.liferay.com/community/wiki/-/wiki/Main/Portlet+Localization+-+Outside+Liferay.

If you are still facing issues, I'd suggest simple solution: Create a language hook (as described here http://www.liferay.com/documentation/liferay-portal/6.2/development/-/ai/override-a-language-properties-hook-liferay-portal-6-2-dev-guide-en) for deploying your resource bundles.

Answer (score 0):

As it was answered, you should add the "resource-bundle" tag correctly. But also, we have to be careful when creating the Resource Bundle file as well.

Create a "**resource**" package inside of your **docroot/WEB-INF/src**. Inside of it, create a new file called **Language.properties**. After that, you are ready to update your portlet.xml file. Find a copy of my portlet.xml below. Pay attention to the way I defined the resource-bundle tag value: resource.Language

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<portlet-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/portlet/portlet-app_2_0.xsd" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/portlet/portlet-app_2_0.xsd http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/portlet/portlet-app_2_0.xsd" version="2.0">

<portlet>
    <portlet-name>birthday</portlet-name>
    <display-name>Birthday</display-name>       
    <portlet-class>
        com.test.exercise.customers.portlet.BirthdayPortlet
    </portlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <name>view-template</name>
        <value>/html/birthday/view.jsp</value>
    </init-param>       
    <expiration-cache>0</expiration-cache>
    <supports>
        <mime-type>text/html</mime-type>
        <portlet-mode>view</portlet-mode>
    </supports>
    <resource-bundle>resource.Language</resource-bundle>
    <portlet-info>
        <title>Birthday</title>
        <short-title>Birthday</short-title>
        <keywords></keywords>
    </portlet-info>     
    <security-role-ref>
        <role-name>administrator</role-name>
    </security-role-ref>
    <security-role-ref>
        <role-name>guest</role-name>
    </security-role-ref>
    <security-role-ref>
        <role-name>power-user</role-name>
    </security-role-ref>
    <security-role-ref>
        <role-name>user</role-name>
    </security-role-ref>
</portlet>
</portlet-app>
```

The location of the **"resource-bundle**" tag also matters within the **portlet.xml** file. If you check the ../portlet-app_2_0.xsd, you can find a "sequence" element that defines the order of the tags inside your portlet.xml file. Make sure that the "resource-bundle" tag is located in the appropriate place.

I hope this helps anyone running in the same issue when localizing a portlet.

Comment: Thank you for the edit Reddy. The <portlet-app> tag is important and wasn' t pasted correctly. Each portlet in the portlet application will have its <portlet> tag inside <portlet-app>.

Answer (score 0):

Maven portlet has a different folder structure, so the location of resource bundle for maven portlet is different. There is already a folder called **resources** for resource-bundles. Put your Language_en.properties directly into this folder.

```
myportlet/src/main/java
                  /resources/Language_en.properties
                  /webapp
```

Then declare your resource-bundle in portlet.xml like so:

`<resource-bundle>Language</resource-bundle>`

It will automatically search in the resources folder for your Language bundles.

If you create subfolders (packages), use the "." as separator, e.g. `<resource-bundle>resource.Language</resource-bundle>`